# SVN error: ( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops atomic-revprops partial-replay ) ) )?

Tags: svn, browser, redmine, bitnami

Can't Access Bitnami Redmine Subversion via browser (a message appeared).

Bitnami Redmine installed and running perfectly: version BitNami Redmine Stack 1.3.0-1

Running on Windows Server 2008 R2 Foundation.

The aim is to access Subversion, as the Manager tool says Subversion is running. Not sure if i need to configure it if its running? Am trying to access it on the server and remotely access it. We also use Visual SVN and that data is backed up and we want to take this backed up data and restore this backup into Redmine's own subversion. I think that's possible?

On any browser on address, I entered: localhost:3690 and I get this message inside the browser:

( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops atomic-revprops partial-replay ) ) )

What does this mean?? and what do I need to do??

Any help is much appreciated! Many thanks!

Answer (score 4):

> ( success ( 2 2 ( ) ( edit-pipeline svndiff1 absent-entries commit-revprops depth log-revprops atomic-revprops partial-replay ) ) )

is the very first response `svnserve` sends during the client-server handshake. And 3690 is the default port number for svn:// protocol.

So, you're using svn:// protocol, not http(s)://.

Your SVN server is actually running, since you receive the message. You can also try to run `svn info svn://localhost` or `svn info svn://localhost/$REPO_NAME` it should print the information on Subversion repository.

Answer (score 2):

We have already replied in http://answers.bitnami.org/questions/6886/cant-access-bitnami-redmine-subversion-via-browser-a-message-appeared in summary the answer to your question is:

You have to check your on starting apache errors and apache2/log/error_log file in order to determine the problem.

Comment: The Error messages were very not useful.... In the application Log of Manage Servers console stated: "Stderr: Unable to start apache" in red font.